# Print linked list segmentation fault

Tags: c, unix, linked-list, ls

I try to code "ls" unix command.
I save my data information in linked list but she seg-fault when i wanna print this linked list :

How i get my data ?

```
#include "ft_ls.h"

static void     my_lstadd(t_data **alst, t_data *new)
{
    new->next = (*alst);
    (*alst) = new;
}

static void     ft_getstat(char *this, t_data **data)
{
    struct stat         fstat;
    struct  passwd  *duser;
    struct  group       *dgroup;
    t_data                  *tmp;

    if (stat(this, &fstat) == -1)
    {
        perror("");
        exit(0);
    }
    tmp = (t_data*)malloc(sizeof(t_data));
    duser = getpwuid(fstat.st_uid);
    dgroup = getgrgid(fstat.st_gid);
    tmp->name = ft_strdup(this);
    tmp->type = ft_type(this);
    tmp->right = ft_right(fstat);
    tmp->link = fstat.st_nlink;
    tmp->owner = ft_strdup(duser->pw_name);
    tmp->grp = ft_strdup(dgroup->gr_name);
    tmp->size = fstat.st_size;
    tmp->date = ft_date_converter(ctime(&fstat.st_mtime));
    my_lstadd(data, tmp);
}

t_data          *ft_getdata(char *dirname, int option)
{
    t_data          *data;
    int             i;
    DIR             *dir;
    struct dirent   *file;

    i = 0;
    dir = opendir(dirname);
    while ((file = readdir(dir)))
    {
        if (option == 1)
            ft_getstat(file->d_name, &data);
        else if (file->d_name[0] != '.')
            ft_getstat(file->d_name, &data);
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return (data);
}
```

My function for printing -l option :

```
#include "ft_ls.h"

static void     ft_get_right(t_data *data)
{
    ft_putchar('\n');
    ft_putchar(ft_type(data->name));
    ft_putright(data->right);
    ft_print_space(3, data->link);
}

void            ft_print_l(t_data **data)
{
    t_data      *ptrdata;

    ptrdata = *data;
    while (ptrdata)
    {
        ft_get_right(ptrdata);
        ft_putnbr(ptrdata->link);
        ft_putchar(' ');
        ft_putstr(ptrdata->owner);
        ft_putchar(' ');
        ft_putstr(ptrdata->grp);
        ft_print_space(6, ptrdata->size);
        ft_putnbr(ptrdata->size);
        ft_putchar(' ');
        ft_putstr(ptrdata->date);
        ft_putchar(' ');
        ft_putstr(ptrdata->name);
        ptrdata = ptrdata->next;
    }
}
```

And the result :

```
./ft_ls -l

-rw-r--r--  1 cgaspart 2017_paris     0 Jan  4 15:26 zebulo
drwxr-xr-x 14 cgaspart 2017_paris   476 Jan 31 13:50 src
drwxr-xr-x 15 cgaspart 2017_paris   510 Feb  2 08:00 obj
-rw-r--r--  1 cgaspart 2017_paris  1758 Jan 30 10:03 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x 67 cgaspart 2017_paris  2278 Jan 31 13:48 libft
drwxr-xr-x  3 cgaspart 2017_paris   102 Jan 31 12:23 include
-rwxr-xr-x  1 cgaspart 2017_paris 14464 Feb  2 08:00 ft_ls
-rw-r--r--  1 cgaspart 2017_paris     8 Jan  4 15:26 auteur[1]    42763 segmentation fault  ./ft_ls -l
```

I guess "ptrdata" in my print function never be NULL then "while" never stop. I tried to set tmp->next to NULL in ft_getstat but that doesn't work.

Comment: How do you develop? Do you use an IDE with a debugger? If not, you should do so. Then you can simply set a breakpoint and step through the code, a line at a time, examining the values of variables and you will quickly find your problem. In future, you won't even need to ask such questions here.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us? Note that it should not be the full program, just enough to show the problem you have. You should also [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially you should learn how to use a debugger to catch the crash, and how to step through the code line by line until you reach the crash.

Comment: I use vim and gcc. Yes gdb is a good one ?

Comment: A hint though: Local variables are by default *uninitialized*. Unless you explicitly initialize them, their values will be *indeterminate* and seemingly random. Now think about what that means for pointers, and what might happen when you try to dereference one such uninitialized pointer.

Comment: In `ft_getdata`, `data` is not initialized while it is used in `my_lstadd(data, tmp);`. To properly end your linked list, you should write `t_data *data = NULL;`

Comment: God, stupid error, sorry for this. Thank you all of us for your help. I just set data to `NULL`.